# How to find results in an array in a Sequelize model

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, json, sequelize.js

I have a model thus:

```
const MenuItem = sequelize.define('MenuItem', {
        ...
        tags: {
            type: DataTypes.JSON,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {});
    return MenuItem;
};
```

I want to build a findAll that can search the tags for one or more possible matches. for example if the tags column has a value:

`["a", "b", "c"]`

then i want to be able to pass either

```
`["a"]`
```

or

```
`["a", "c"]`
```

to my server and search for possible matches. I've tried using Op.contains and Op.in but both result in errors. Am i going down the wrong path here? How would I go about building this query in sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured something out. I think its a little hacky but it gets the job done. If anyone else can come up with a better solution I'd appreciate it.

in my controller, first I check to see if a tags have been passed to it (will be a string since GET requests dont have bodies, thus the split), and if so:

```
            const tagArr = tags.split("|")
            if (tagArr.length > 1) {
                params.tags = { [Op.and]: tagArr.map(e => {
                    return { [Op.like]: [`%${e}%`]}
                })}
            } else {
                params.tags = { [Op.like]: [`%${tagArr[0]}%`]}
            }
```

I'm not 100% sure why the value for op.like had to be in an array too. at first i thought that meant I could just pass it 1 or more values but then it would return if  I matched any of them (then later for some reason it just stopped working. not sure what I changed there) but I want them to match ALL present tags. Therefore inside a Op.and, I map the tagArr into a series of Op.likes. if theres only one element in tagArr then I simply skip the op.and